# I'm using Bash in "vi mode". What's the hotkey sequence to edit the current command line using an external editor?

Tags: bash, text-editors, vi, key-binding, readline

In [Bash](http://enwp.org/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)'s "Emacs mode" (`set -o emacs`), I can edit the current command line in my favorite external $EDITOR. All I have to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

But, because I have switched to Bash's "vi mode" (`set -o vi`), this key sequence doesn't do anything.  In "vi mode", how can I launch an external editor in order to compose longer commands?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The emacs mode binding executes command edit-and-execute-command. To see which binding executes it in vi mode you can give command:

```
$ bind -m vi -q edit-and-execute-command
edit-and-execute-command is not bound to any keys.
```

Easiest would be to add a binding for it

```
$ bind -m vi-insert '"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command'
```

To make it permanent, you can add it to ~/.inputrc as

```
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is the answer I am looking for. Can you show me how to trigger the editor using ctrl+x,e combined rather than just ctrl+ x?

Comment: Ok. I edited the answer. Sorry for not making it complete in the first place.

Comment: How do I refresh my `.inputrc` file to test that this works?

Comment: You start a new shell. `bash` or `exec bash` if you want to replace your current shell.

Answer (score 8):

### The answer

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go into vi-command mode, then press <kbd>v</kbd>. Bash will start your your chosen $EDITOR. If you haven't chosen one, Bash will start vi (the visual editor).

### Explanation

Why does Bash's <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> start vi?

Because Bash's `bashline.c` includes the function call:

```
rl_bind_key_if_unbound_in_map ('v', vi_edit_and_execute_command, vi_movement_keymap);
```

What is `vi_edit_and_execute_command`? It's a Bash C function, defined elsewhere in `bashline.c`.

One aside. I have experimented a bit, and the following is what I now suspect is true. Binding Bash C functions is weird. You can do it from within Bash's source code, but it seems impossible to do so by using the  `bind` builtin at the Bash prompt. And, once you've done it, the `bind` builtin doesn't seem to even recognize that it's been done.

I thank [Glenn Jackman](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/7057/glenn-jackman) for [pointing out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/how-do-i-edit-current-shell-command-in-vi#88528) that <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> is the answer, and dualbus and Riviera of Freenode #bash for helping me to figure out the explanation above.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify the default editor as `vi`, then you need to set 
the environment variable `EDITOR`:

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

Now saying <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> would launch `vi`.

Answer (score 2):

How to disable `edit-and-execute-command` for the `v` key in vi\vi-command\vi-movement mode:

You cannot rebind it to `nop`, since it will automatically be rebound (see post by 
unforgettableid). Instead, you can bind it to `set-mark` if you don't use that.
`.inputrc`:

```
set keymap vi-command
v: set-mark
# If you want to bind it to something else, e.g. Ctrl-v:
# "\C-v": edit-and-execute-command
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's more like an extended-length comment. ❧ Next time, please ask a new question and [answer it yourself](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).